# AttributeError: 'YOLO' object has no attribute 'tune'

Tags: python

`pip install -U ultralytics "ray[tune]"`

`pip install wandb`

```py
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

result_grid = model.tune(data='data.yaml', use_ray=True)
```

After running the code I got the `AttributeError: 'YOLO' object has no attribute 'tune'` error.

Can you please tell me how to resolve this error?

I have upgraded the pip version as well still showing the the same error.

Comment: Please include your full code. Where are you importing `YOLO`?